# jQuery Dropdownchecklist tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am using the jQuery Drop Down Check List component:

http://github.com/scottwb/jquery.ui.dropdownchecklist

However, it doesn't seem that there is support to add a tooltip to such a drop down. Usually, you just add the 'title' tag for every option and a tooltip is automatically shown. However, this is not the case with this component.

Does anybody know how can I implement this?

This is the code I usually use for drop down items tooltips:

```
<select id="MySelect">
    <option title="ToolTip1">Item 1</option>
    <option title="ToolTip2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you paste some of your generated HTML and JS code?

Comment: Nevermind, I dropped this. I used a workaround. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I dropped this. I used a workaround.